# What MAPI property should be used to set the "Always prompt for logon credentials" property?

Tags: c++, windows, outlook, mapi

I'm trying to write a code to create an outlook profile.

**Requirements** - I want to toggle the "Always prompt for logon credentials" box.

**Problem** - I've searched a lot out there, and got no clue. In here, i found a registry key. But Im looking for the MAPITAG .

Comment: Hi Vidhya, Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you post your code and some reproducible example?

Comment: Hey thanks ! I've not started coding yet. Im doing a study now. I found some properties like PR_CONFIG_FLAGS for the configuration of cached mode. Im looking for a similar property to configure the "Always prompt for logon credentials" feature. @WoodChopper

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is the same PR_CONFIG_FLAGS for which the flag is 0x000C.